# How do I enable HTTP compression under apache2?

Tags: apache-2.2, compression

How do I configure Apache2 to support [HTTP compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This requires the `deflate` module, so enable that. Under Ubuntu (which is what I'm using), the command for that is `a2enmod deflate`.

Then, use `SetOutputFilter` on your `Proxy` or `Directory` directive:

```
<ProxyMatch "^http://localhost:8080/($|app/)">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    SetOutputFilter Deflate
</ProxyMatch>
```

Or:

```
<Directory /var/www>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    SetOutputFilter Deflate
</Directory>
```

Comment: For other distros, you load the module by using "LoadModule deflate_module /path/to/module/mod_deflate.so" -- Just a couple of cents to a good answer.

Answer (score 4):

As the Wikipedia entry you link to notes, you can use **mod_deflate** or **mod_gzip**. See here an [example with mod_gzip](http://www.schroepl.net/projekte/mod_gzip/config.htm), which is what I use.

Answer (score 1):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ...     
   DeflateBufferSize 16384
   DeflateCompressionLevel 5
   DeflateMemLevel 9
   DeflateWindowSize 15

   <Location / >
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript
   </Location>
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your deploy place this in your conf.d or extras folder as mod_deflate.conf:

```
# Enable mod_deflate (gzip)
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Do not attempt to compress the following extensions
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
    \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|swf|flv|zip|gz|tar|mp3|mp4|m4v)$ no-gzip dont-vary
```

Restart apache and mod_deflate will occur on all extensions not matching the regex above, this reduces the overall CPU overhead as it prevents mod_deflate from attempting to compress a format you will see little or no compression for (because it is already compressed).

To see what exactly is being compressed, and the compression ratio, place this in your

```
# Deflate accurate logging
    DeflateFilterNote Input instream
    DeflateFilterNote Output outstream
    DeflateFilterNote Ratio ratio
    LogFormat '"%r" %{outstream}n/%{instream}n (%{ratio}n%%)' deflate
    CustomLog logs/yourdomain_deflate.log
```